# How to use CSSStyleSheet.insertRule() properly?

Tags: javascript, css, stylesheet

I can't figure out where I'm going wrong here :/. When I run this code, all I get is a blank  element. I can't seem to get the insertRule method to do anything (not even produce an error). Am I missing something?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    var sheet = (function() {
        // Create the <style> tag
        var style = document.createElement("style");

        // WebKit hack
        style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(""));

        // Add the <style> element to the page
        document.head.appendChild(style);

        return style.sheet;
    })();
    sheet.insertRule("\
        #gridContainer {\
            width: 100%;\
            height: 100%;\
        }\
    ", 0);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems to work on Firefox and Chromium.

Comment: I am getting a blank <style></style> tag in Firefox and Chromium... I edited my question to show the entire code I'm running. Not sure what's going wrong...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It is slightly confusing but your code does actually work, it is just that you can't see the inserted rules in the XML tree returned.

To verify that your code works, there are two tests you can do:

```js
var style = (function() {
    // Create the <style> tag
    var style = document.createElement("style");

    // WebKit hack
    style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(""));

    // Add the <style> element to the page
    document.head.appendChild(style);
  
    console.log(style.sheet.cssRules); // length is 0, and no rules

    return style;
})();
style.sheet.insertRule('.foo{color:red;}', 0);
console.log(style.sheet.cssRules); // length is 1, rule added
```

```html
<p class="foo">
  I am some text
</p>
```

Run the above snippet, and you can see that the CSS rule does apply. And the `cssRules` property changes as well in the console.

This is often noted when browser extensions generate custom style-sheets appended to the DOM, and while debugging they appear as empty style-sheets in the inspector.

Comment: Ha! I should have thought to test for that. Since it appeared empty in inspector, I made the assumption that it was not applied. Thanks Awal :)

Comment: @user2522373 no problem :) Next time, just remember that the console is a silent witness to everything.

Comment: Strange that the text doesn't appear inside the element, as one might expect. Though I'm seeing that it does work regardless in my use cases.

Comment: You should explain more about that *`WebKit hack`*, provide a reference link  or something

Answer (score 1):

This version is based on Awal's answer and Totally Pwn CSS with Javascript from [web archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20130709232042/http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Totally_Pwn_CSS_with_Javascript).
The **id** parameter is useful for accesing the styleSheet with getElementById, and the **media** parameter is optinal and defauts to 'screen'.
I am returning the **styleSheet.sheet**, this is just my preference.

```
function createStyleSheet (id, media) {
    var el   = document.createElement('style');
    // WebKit hack
    el.appendChild(document.createTextNode(''));
    el.type  = 'text/css';
    el.rel   = 'stylesheet';
    el.media = media || 'screen';
    el.id    = id;
    document.head.appendChild(el);
    return el.sheet;
}
```

Comment: Setting all those attributes on the `<style>` element are long un-needed... you should discard them. only the `media` is somehow valuable for uncommon situations.