# JavaScript stylesheet.insertRule not inserting rule but returns no errors or exceptions

Tags: javascript

I need to create some dynamic css and trying to use insertRule. I am creating a style tag, then attempting to use insertRule within a loop to create a number of rules.

What's happening: Style tag is generated and added to the head, no rules insterted to the tag. No errors in console.

Here is the relevant code:

```
let addCSSRule = function(sheet, selector, rules, index) {
        sheet.insertRule(selector + "{" + rules + "}", index);
    };

    let styleTagGenerator = function() {
        let tag = document.createElement('style');
        tag.id = 'myskills_dynamic_style';
        tag.type = 'text/css';
        document.head.appendChild(tag);
    };
```

Then in the loop where I call the addCSSRule function. I have played around with the index:

```
for(let key in response) {
     let val = response[key];
      let selector = '.progressbar-bg span.progressbar-' + key + ':after';
      let rule = 'animation-name: pb-' + val + '-after';
      let styleTag = document.getElementById('myskills_dynamic_style').sheet;
                        addCSSRule(styleTag, selector, rule);
  }
```

Comment: I suppose the rules are added to the stylesheet object, but they are not reflected to the markup.

Comment: Notice also, that `addCSSRule` expects four parameters, but you're passing only three. This doesn't have an effect to the execution, though.

Comment: well, when inspecting the source I can see the style tag in the head appear, but it doesn't add any rules to the tag. Not seeing anything reflected in markup, so yes you're correct.

Comment: This happens probably because you can manipulate also linked stylesheet via StyleSheet objects, and link elements don't have content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code does work. Note that, when using `CSSStyleSheet.insertRule()`, the rules are actually inserted into the style sheet although they do not show up in the XML tree. Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28930990/2692307

Below an working example, I've just added a sample dataset and changed the css rules to better prove the example.

```js
let addCSSRule = function(sheet, selector, rules, index) {
        sheet.insertRule(selector + "{" + rules + "}", index);
    };

let styleTagGenerator = function() {
    let tag = document.createElement('style');
    tag.id = 'myskills_dynamic_style';
    tag.type = 'text/css';
    document.head.appendChild(tag);
};

let response = { // Example object
  test: 'bada55'
};

for(let key in response) {
    let val = response[key];
    let selector = '.progressbar-bg span.progressbar-' + key + ''; // Removed :after to visualize it better
    let rule = 'background-color: #' + val + ''; // Use bg-color instead of animation to visualize it better
    let styleTag = document.getElementById('myskills_dynamic_style').sheet;
    addCSSRule(styleTag, selector, rule, response.length);
}
```

```html
<style id="myskills_dynamic_style"></style>

<div class="progressbar-bg">
  <span class="progressbar-test">abc</span>
</div>
```