# How to use CSSStyleSheet.insertRule() in Internet Explorer properly?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11

I am getting a "IndexSizeError" error in Internet Explorer 11 using this code:

```
var style = document.createElement('style');
document.head.appendChild(style);
style.sheet.insertRule('td {overflow: visible}');
```

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule the index parameter is optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In IE11 the error is fixed if I add the index parameter:

```
var style = document.createElement('style');
document.head.appendChild(style);
style.sheet.insertRule('td {overflow: visible}', 0);
```

related: [How to use CSSStyleSheet.insertRule() properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28930846/how-to-use-cssstylesheet-insertrule-properly)

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution for this issue. I suggest you to try to mark your own answer as an accepted answer for this question after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.